# What other properties can be used besides 'data' and 'position' to store API response data in a cytoscape element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, github, cytoscape.js

```
elements=[ {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 75, 'y': 75}}, {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}}, {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two'}} ];
```

Comment: I want to add the response of API so that it can be utilized further in the program.

Comment: I want to fetch API response and store that and reuse it to display repositories. Basically want to customise the node so that it can store API response.